# Java Hot swap failed and schema change is not implemented

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, curl

I work on a Java Spring boot app where I get the error of Hot-swap failed and schema change is not implemented and the operation is not supported by the VM. Afterward, the table is truncated and have no data at all.

[image]

I have 2 models provided below,

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "countryName")
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String countryName;


    @Column(name = "currencyName")
    @NotNull
    @NotEmpty
    private String currencyName;


    /*
     * total steps is for the keepign the history of the user movement
     * */
    @Column(name = "totalSteps")
    @Min(value = 0L, message = "The value must be positive")
    private int totalSteps;

    /*
     * current steps is for providing the user reward. We will need to set
     * it to zero after processing the user payment
     * */
    @Column(name = "currentSteps")
    @Min(value = 0L, message = "The value must be positive")
    private int currentSteps;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<RewardList> rewardLists = new ArrayList<>();

    public User() {

    }

    public User(@NotNull @NotEmpty String name, @NotNull @NotEmpty String countryName) {
        this.name = name;
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public User(@NotNull @NotEmpty String name, @NotNull @NotEmpty String countryName, @Min(value = 0L, message = "The value must be positive") int totalSteps) {
        this.name = name;
        this.countryName = countryName;
        this.totalSteps = totalSteps;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getCountryName() {
        return countryName;
    }

    public String getCurrencyName() {
        return currencyName;
    }

    public void setCurrencyName(String currencyName) {
        this.currencyName = currencyName;
    }

    public void setCountryName(String countryName) {
        this.countryName = countryName;
    }

    public int getTotalSteps() {
        return totalSteps;
    }

    public void setTotalSteps(int totalSteps) {
        this.totalSteps = totalSteps;
    }

    public int getCurrentSteps() {
        return currentSteps;
    }

    public void setCurrentSteps(int currentSteps) {
        this.currentSteps = currentSteps;
    }

    public List<RewardList> getRewardLists() {
        return rewardLists;
    }

    public void setRewardLists(RewardList rl) {
        this.rewardLists.add(rl);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof User)) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return getTotalSteps() == user.getTotalSteps() &&
                getCurrentSteps() == user.getCurrentSteps() &&
                getId().equals(user.getId()) &&
                getName().equals(user.getName()) &&
                getCountryName().equals(user.getCountryName()) &&
                getRewardLists().equals(user.getRewardLists());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId(), getName(), getCountryName(), getTotalSteps(), getCurrentSteps(), getRewardLists());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", countryName='" + countryName + '\'' +
                ", totalSteps=" + totalSteps +
                ", currentSteps=" + currentSteps +
                '}';
    }
}


@Entity
public class RewardList {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "reward")
    @Min(value = 0L, message = "The value must be positive")
    private double reward;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    private User user;

    public RewardList() {
    }

    public RewardList(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public RewardList(@Min(value = 0L, message = "The value must be positive") double reward) {
        this.reward = reward;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public double getReward() {
        return reward;
    }

    public void setReward(double reward) {
        this.reward = reward;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof RewardList)) return false;
        RewardList list = (RewardList) o;
        return Double.compare(list.getReward(), getReward()) == 0 &&
                getId().equals(list.getId()) &&
                getUser().equals(list.getUser());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getId(), getReward(), getUser());
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "RewardList{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", reward=" + reward +
                ", user=" + user +
                '}';
    }
}
```

The end-point where I have this issue provided below,

```
// $ curl -X PUT http://localhost:8080/api/v1/users/calculateReward?userId=1 | jq

@PutMapping("/calculateReward")
public ResponseEntity<Object> calculateReward(@RequestParam("userId") Long userId) {

    Optional<User> optional = userService.findById(userId);

    if (!optional.isPresent()) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT).build();
    }

    User user = optional.get();

    double reward = user.getCurrentSteps() * Parameters.REWARD_PER_STEPS_EUR;

    RewardList list = new RewardList();

    list.setUser(user);
    list.setReward(reward);
    rewardListService.save(list);

    user.setCurrentSteps(0);
    user.setRewardLists(list);
    userService.save(user);

    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

    double convertionRateToEuro = currencyMap.get(user.getCurrencyName());
    double rewardConverted = reward * convertionRateToEuro;

    json.put("name", user.getName());
    json.put("currency", user.getCurrencyName());
    json.put("reward", rewardConverted);

    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(json);
}
```

Does anyone know what is going on and can provide a solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason and below I provide a solution. We will need to save the models based on the hierarchy. HotSwap doesn't support adding methods or hierarchy changes as indicated by the error messages. It's the limitation of Java HotSwap, not IntelliJ IDEA. The proper way of code sequence will be,

```
    User user = optional.get();

    RewardList list = new RewardList();

    list.setUser(user);
    list.setReward(reward);

    user.setCurrentSteps(0);
    user.setRewardLists(list);


    // first save the User
    userService.save(user);

    // Then, save the RewardList as it has one to many relations
    rewardListService.save(list);
```